Roots on the positive semiplane
I'd like to prove that there is no complex roots with positive real parts in the equation
$$(a+x)^\alpha+b=0,\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+,\quad \alpha\in(0,1].$$
One argued against this hypothesis in the following therms:
$$x=b^{1/\alpha}e^{i\pi/\alpha}-a,$$
particularly, for $\alpha=1/2$,
$$x=b^2-a,$$
which can be positive if $b^2>a$.
But then we are writing
$$(a+x)^{1/2}+b=(b^2)^{1/2}+b=0\therefore \sqrt{b^2}=-b$$
...?
Any comments are welcome for more explanation.
And could one give hypothesis about $a$ and $b$ so the aim is valid?

For any complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$, $r>0,\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ or $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}+i\pi}=-\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ depending on the branch you have. If you don't make a branch cut, then $z \mapsto z^{\alpha}$  it's a multi valued function which will lead to problems that you are facing. To make the problem rigorous, define the branch cut of the function $z \mapsto z^{\alpha} = r^{\alpha}e^{i\theta\alpha}$ by putting a constraint on the argument, Arg$(z^{\alpha}) \in [0,2\pi\alpha)$. With this restriction, the proposed solution is not valid, since $(b^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{\alpha}})^{\alpha} = be^{i\pi}$ will have argument greater or equal to that $2\pi \alpha$ for $\alpha \le \frac{1}{2}$. For $\frac{2}{3}> \alpha > \frac{1}{2}$, $z = b^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a$ seems to be correct, but it won't satisfy your second constraint of positive real part, if you add the additional condition $$\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)}< \frac{a}{b^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}. $$ This forces $$ \Re\{b^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a\} = b^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)}-a<0.$$

Thank you! Please, could you explain why $\frac{2}{3}>\alpha$?

For $\frac{2}{3} < \alpha < 1$, I think $\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)} <0$, so the real part is always negative in that case.
